# Versioning etiquette in open source projects?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, open-source

I have forked a gem on github that I have made several important changes to and I plan on submitting a pull request.  Before I do, I was wondering whether I should bump the minor version number or let the gem maintainers decide how to version it.

Having read "[Etiquette: Version bump my fork of opensource project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484548/etiquette-version-bump-my-fork-of-opensource-project)" and "[Git fork version etiquette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871403/git-fork-version-etiquette)", it seems that most people just bump the version themselves.

To anyone who owns an open source project, do you think this is presumptuous or am I just being paranoid?

Comment: I think you should let them decide the version number. You have no idea how many changes they're going to pull in, or when they're going to do it, or whether your change will be part of a major bump or a minor increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you forked a repo and you are contributing back to the same repo, then don't change the version and don't make any change to the Ruby gem files, unless strictly necessary.

Leave the maintainer the freedom to decide when the library should be released and which version to assign. You don't know if the maintainer has other plans or is working on something else.

You don't even know if and when your changes are going to be merged. There are chances that other versions are released before your changes are incorporated and you will increase the risk of conflicts with files that are not even part of the meaning of the patch (such as versioning).

I rejected a few patches in the past because approving them meant to deploy unnecessary changes to the version that were breaking my roadmap. As a general rule, I reject every patch where the changes are not limited to the feature/bugfix the committer is proposing. If you check the contribution guidelines of the gems published on GitHub you will see that several projects mention this rule.

If you are publishing the gem as a fork, than you are free to do whatever you want.